# Unable to display the simulation with EDAPlayground compiler

Tags: myhdl, edaplayground

I have tried the following code from myHDL manual on EDAPlayground.com, but it didn't print anything out for me. Can anyone show me why and how to solve this?

My configuration on the site is outlined here.

```
Testbench+Design : Python only
Methodology : MyHDL 0.8
```

---

```python
from random import randrange
from myhdl import *

    ACTIVE_LOW, INACTIVE_HIGH = 0, 1
    
    def Inc(count, enable, clock, reset, n):

    """ Incrementer with enable.

    count -- output
    enable -- control input, increment when 1
    clock -- clock input
    reset -- asynchronous reset input
    n -- counter max value

    """

    @always_seq(clock.posedge, reset=reset)
    def incLogic():
        if enable:
            count.next = (count + 1) % n

    return incLogic

    def testbench():

    count, enable, clock = [Signal(intbv(0)) for i in range(3)]
    
    # Configure your reset signal here (active type, async/sync)
    reset = ResetSignal(0,active=ACTIVE_LOW,async=True)
    
    

    ## DUT to be instantiated
    inc_1 = Inc(count, enable, clock, reset, n=4)

    HALF_PERIOD = delay(10)


    ## forever loop : clock generator
    
    @always(HALF_PERIOD)
    def clockGen():
        clock.next = not clock

    ## Stimulus generator
    @instance
    def stimulus():
        reset.next = ACTIVE_LOW
        yield clock.negedge
        reset.next = INACTIVE_HIGH
        for i in range(12):
            enable.next = min(1, randrange(3))
            yield clock.negedge
        raise StopSimulation

    @instance
    def monitor():
        print "enable  count"
        yield reset.posedge
        while 1:
            yield clock.posedge
            yield delay(1)
            print "   %s      %s" % (enable, count)

    return clockGen, stimulus, inc_1, monitor


    tb = testbench()
    
    def main():
        Simulation(tb).run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the main() function at the end. 
E.g., add a line

```
main()
```

at the end, or better, use Python's idiom of

```
if __name__=="__main__": 
     main()
```